# Homebrew upgrades everything randomly

Tags: macos, homebrew

Why does homebrew decide to upgrade everything sometimes?
(I don't seem to see many complaints about this, so maybe I have some weird setting on by default?)

Typically I will homebrew upgrade/install  to upgrade 1 formula.
Most times, it just does finishes this and exits.
Sometimes though, after finishing, it will continue to upgrade every single formula I have.
Why is this desired behavior?

Comment: I'd very much like to know the answer too! It doesn't even ask, it just goes and does it. It's infuriating.